# how to change default keyboard shortcuts in website

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to change the default keyboard shortcuts in a website?  For example the default browser shortcut for select all is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> can I change it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>?, or full screen is <kbd>F11</kbd>, can I change it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? As a user I'm really annoyed if an application or website changes the default behavior of the browser or system especially for such fundamental parts as shortcuts. And you never get something consistent if it should be cross platform.

Comment: @t.niese I dont want to change stuff that interferes with user experience , only alter stuff like ctrl a in a document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their is a javascript library [mousetrap](https://craig.is/killing/mice) which can be used to create custom shortcuts for website.
after adding this library you can simply call

```
Mousetrap.bind('ctrl+r', function(e) {
  // do stuff here
});
```

refer to given Mousetrap link for more info

Comment: I tried Mousetrap it wasn't doing anything, could it be because i have the shortcuts.js in too?